# Maximum of the differences using shell script or awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have several files, each having two columns with some wrong data as large negative values.

file_1.txt

```
3       4
4       5
2       4
-10023  -9821
4       7
9       1
3       5
3       4
```

file_2.txt

```
6       2
4       5
2       4
-98323  -83432
-208932 4
7       17
20      3
20      2
```

file_3.txt

```
4       4
2       4
2       4
-129923 -1209923
2       3
12      3
2       4
7       1
```

I would like to print the maximum of the differences between the column 1 and column 2 in the above files without considering the wrong data. In simple way,

```
Maximum [ ($1 - $2) file*.txt ]
```

Desired output

```
ofile.txt
4
-1
-2
-99999
-1
9
17
18
```

Comment: `but not getting the result.` but are you getting something at all? What are you getting? `I would like to replace all the wrong values with -99999` so... add `else print -99999`? Or print like a `print A` and then when merging files to `if ($1 == "A" || $2 == "A"...) print -999999`.

Comment: Are all the lines with negative numbers ones you don't want to consider?

Comment: You have **several steps** (commands) in your algorithm. So, which exact step **firstly** gives the wrong result? Isn't this the **last step** which just prints the maximum value in files `file*.txt`? So it the problem is completely unrelated to "maximum of the differences". Note also, that `file*.txt` matches not only *generated files* `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` but also you **original files** `file_1.txt`, `file_2.txt` and `file_3.txt`, which is probably not what do you want.

Comment: You should include some lines in your sample data with negative numbers you *don't* want excluded, for completness sake.

Comment: And do all your input files have the same number of lines?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry for letting you confused. Although I had the problem in the maximum, but I was looking for a single script to work altogether. My individual scripts to obtain file1.txt, file2.txt and so on, were not efficient at all.

Comment: @Shawn Many thanks. your script is working for all type of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with your sample input in a single pass (Assuming all data files have the same number of lines):

```
$ awk '$1 > -1000 && $2 > -1000 {
         d = $1 - $2
         if (FNR in diffs) {
           if (diffs[FNR] < d)
             diffs[FNR] = d
         } else {
           diffs[FNR] = d
         }
       }
       END {
         for (n = 1; n <= FNR; n++) {
           if (n in diffs)
             print diffs[n]
           else 
             print -99999
         }
       }' file_*.txt
4
-1
-2
-99999
-1
9
17
18
```