# Maximum of the differences

Tags: shell, awk

This question it related to one my earlier question: [Maximum of the differences using shell script or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652288/maximum-of-the-differences-using-shell-script-or-awk)

I have several files, each having two columns with some wrong data as large negative values.

```
file_1.txt

   05Jan2020     3       4
   06Jan2020     4       5
   07Jan2020     2       4
   08Jan2020    -10023  -9821
   09Jan2020     4       7
   10Jan2020     9       1
   11Jan2020     3       5
   12Jan2020     3       4

file_2.txt

    05Jan2020     6       2
    06Jan2020     4       5
    07Jan2020     2       4
    08Jan2020    -98323  -83432
    09Jan2020    -208932  4
    10Jan2020     7       17
    11Jan2020     20      3
    12Jan2020     20      2
    
file_3.txt

  05Jan2020       4       4
  06Jan2020       2       4
  07Jan2020       2       4
  08Jan2020      -129923 -1209923
  09Jan2020       2       3
  10Jan2020       12      3
  11Jan2020       2       4
  12Jan2020       7       1
```

I would like to print the maximum of the differences between the column 2 and column 3 in the above files without considering the wrong (large Integers) data. In simple way,

```
Print $1, [maximum($2-$3)<file*.txt]
```

Desired output

```
ofile.txt

       05Jan2020       4
       06Jan2020      -1
       07Jan2020      -2
       08Jan2020      -99999
       09Jan2020      -1
       10Jan2020       9
       11Jan2020       17
       12Jan2020       18
```

I am trying with the following script. It is giving correct results, but it is not printing the dates correctly. It prints the last date only.

```
awk '$2 > -1000 && $3 > -1000 {
         d = $2 - $3
         if (FNR in diffs) {
           if (diffs[FNR] < d)
             diffs[FNR] = d
         } else {
           diffs[FNR] = d
         }
       }
       END {
         for (n = 1; n <= FNR; n++) {
           if (n in diffs)
             printf "%10s%10s\n",$1,diffs[n]
           else
             printf "%10s%10s\n",$1,"-99999"
      }'file_*.txt
```

I am getting following result:

```
   12Jan2020       4
   12Jan2020      -1
   12Jan2020      -2
   12Jan2020      -99999
   12Jan2020      -1
   12Jan2020       9
   12Jan2020       17
   12Jan2020       18
```

Comment: Because in your END section, you should not be using `$1` It has the value of the last line read (is this documented?).

Comment: Didn't you [already ask pretty much the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652288/maximum-of-the-differences-using-shell-script-or-awk)?

Comment: You code contains syntax errors. Missing a `}` and a space before `file_*.txt`.

Comment: @Shawn : Yes, but now the O.P. has some reasonable code attached to the problem. (Ha, which I see now that you supplied in the previous). Oh well ;-/

Comment: @shellter That's why it rang a bell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save first column in an array, too.

Insert before your `END` section `{dates[FNR] = $1}` and replace both `$1` with `dates[n]`.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, have written on mobile so couldn't test it as of now, should work but.

```
awk '
{
  diff=$2-$3
  a[$1]=(a[$1]!="" && a[$1]>diff?a[$1]:diff)
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i,a[i]
  }
}' *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use Perl, which you'll find on any linux distribution.

```
perl -e '
    $bad = -99999;
    while(<ARGV>){
        chomp(@cols=split /\h+/);
        $diff = $cols[1]<0 || $cols[2]<0 ? $bad : $cols[1]-$cols[2];
        $old = $result{$cols[0]} || $bad;
        $result{$cols[0]} = $old < $diff ? $diff : $old;
    }
    foreach $k (sort keys %result) {print "$k    $result{$k}\n";}
' file*.txt
```

As a one-line:

```
perl -e '$bad=-99999;while(<ARGV>){chomp(@c=split /\h+/);$diff=$c[1]<0||$c[2]<0?$bad:$c[1]-$c[2];$old=$result{$c[0]}||$bad;$result{$c[0]}=$old<$diff?$diff:$old;}foreach $k(sort keys %result){print "$k    $result{$k}\n";}' file*
```

Result:

```
05Jan2020    4
06Jan2020    -1
07Jan2020    -2
08Jan2020    -99999
09Jan2020    -1
10Jan2020    9
11Jan2020    17
12Jan2020    18
```